# Difficulty calling unmanaged dll from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, unmanaged

I'm going bleary-eyed trying to figure out why I can't call an external method in an old C++ .dll from my C# application.

Here's the function header:

```
int __export FAR PASCAL SimplePGPEncryptFile(
                                      HWND hWnd1,
                                      LPSTR InputFileName,
                                      LPSTR OutputFileName,
                                      BOOL SignIt,
                                      BOOL Wipe,
                                      BOOL Armor,
                                      BOOL TextMode,
                                      BOOL IDEAOnly,
                                      BOOL UseUntrustedKeys,
                                      LPSTR RecipientList,
                                      LPSTR SignerKeyID,
                                      int SignerBufferLen,
                                      LPSTR SignerPassphrase,
                                      int SignerPwdBufferLen,
                                      LPSTR IDEAPassphrase,
                                      int IDEAPwdBufferLen,
                                      LPSTR PublicKeyRingName,
                                      LPSTR PrivateKeyRingName);
```

Here's my C# declaration:

```
        [DllImport("smplpgp_32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SimplePGPEncryptFile(
        IntPtr hWnd1,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string InputFileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string OutputFileName,
        bool SignIt,
        bool Wipe,
        bool Armor,
        bool TextMode,
        bool IDEAOnly,
        bool UseUntrustedKeys,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string RecipientList,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string SignerKeyID,
        int SignerBufferLen,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string SignerPassphrase,
        int SignerPwdBufferLen,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string IDEAPassphrase,
        int IDEAPwdBufferLen,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string PublicKeyRingName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string PrivateKeyRingName);
```

When I call this method I'm getting one of the two following errors (declared in the header):

```
#define SIMPLEPGPENCRYPTFILE_RECIPIENTLISTDOESNOTENDWITHNEWLINE    408
#define SIMPLEPGPENCRYPTFILE_RECIPIENTLISTDOESNOTSTARTWITHGOODCODECHAR   409
```

This is also defined as a constant in the header:

```
#define INCLUDE_ONLYUSERIDS 1
```

This is C++ code that is known to work calling this function:

```
    char recipients[512];
recipients[0] = INCLUDE_ONLYUSERIDS;
strcat(strcpy(&recipients[1], rID), "\n"); \\ rID is equal to "CA"
return 0 == SimplePGPEncryptFile(INI.m_hWnd,
    (char*)plain, (char*)cipher,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    1, // UseUntrustedKeys
    recipients,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    PGPKM.pub, 0); //PGPKM.pub is declared earlier
```

Passing this for the 'RecipientList' parameter gives me the '409' error:

```
string recipientList = "1CA\n\0";
```

Passing this for the 'RecipientList' parameter gives me the '408' error:

```
char[] recipients = new char[512];
recipients[0] = '1';
recipients[1] = 'C';
recipients[2] = 'A';
recipients[3] = '\n'; // also tried '\r', then '\n'
recipients[4] = Char.MinValue;
string paramValue = recipients.ToString();
```

Can anyone spot an obvious oversight on my part?  I feel like I've got everything I need to solve this, but nothing is working as expected.

Side note: I'm successfully calling a different function in the same .dll.  Also, I've experimented using StringBuilder to construct the RecipientList parameter.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: recipients[0] = INCLUDE_ONLYUSERIDS; -- Doesn't this turn into recipients[0] = 1; which is different to recipients[0] = '1'; - the C# equivalent would be recipients[0] = (char)1;

Comment: What's the purpose of recipients[4] = Char.MinValue;?

Comment: In the code that works, the line strcat(strcpy(&recipients[1], rID), "\n"):  what does the resulting string look like, i.e. where did the \n get copied to?  After 512 bytes?  Or is it smart enough to truncate whatever part of recipients[] isn't used?  Been a while since my C++ days, forgive me

Comment: James B - I was trying to absolutely make sure my string was mull-terminated, which you guessed correctly in a later comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
string recipientList = (char) 1 + "CA\n\0";
```

Did some digging based on Jeffora's comment... He's probably right, my first suggestion probably won't buy you anything.  I wrote some test code, here's what I found:

When you use this code:

```
string recipientList = "1CA\n\0";
```

The bytes you end up with on the inside of the function after marshaling as an LPStr are:

```
49-67-65-10-0
```

Which looks like what you want.

When you use this code:

```
char[] recipients = new char[512];
recipients[0] = '1';
recipients[1] = 'C';
recipients[2] = 'A';
recipients[3] = '\n'; // also tried '\r', then '\n'
recipients[4] = Char.MinValue;
string paramValue = recipients.ToString();
```

The bytes you get on the inside of the function after marshaling as an LPStr are:

```
83-121-115-116-101-109-46-67-104-97-114-91-93
```

Which is ASCII for "System.Char[]".  So you'll definitely need to use an encoder to turn that char[] into the string you want.

As for why the first string isn't working... I suspect your DLL is really looking for the value '1', and not the ascii character for '1' (49).   In the code that works, you say:

```
recipients[0] = INCLUDE_ONLYUSERIDS;
```

where INCLUDE_ONLYUSERIDS = 1

**Try this:**

```
string recipientList = (char) 1 + "CA\n\0";
```

Original answer:
*I believe the issue is that Char.ToString() treats the char as a unicode character, but you're marshalling as LPStr, not LPWStr.  LPStr is looking for a string of ANSII characters.*

To fix this, try using a byte array.

```
byte[] recipients= new byte[512];
 ...
//  Pass this string to SimplePGPEncryptFile
string recipientsToPass = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(recipients);
```

Comment: Fairly sure the Marshaller takes care of marshalling from .NET Unicode strings to the requested ASCII string, as he has specified that the string type is ASCII via the MarshalAs attributes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you're right, that probably isn't buying you a bloody thing.  I should stop trying to answer questions after midnight : P

Comment: But doesn't the marshaller also add on the 0 to the end of the string automatically?  I think that's what he's trying to do with recipients[4] = Char.MinValue;

Comment: I take it back, he does need an encoder of some sorts, because just calling Char.ToString() isn't doing it.  See my revised answer

Comment: this should be ok: string str = (char) 1 + "CA\n"; You don't need to add the terminating null. strcat creates one, and the .NET pinvoke platform as well. And the 1st char needs to be 1, not '1' for sure.

Comment: I thought the pinvoke would add a terminating null, as well, but when I tested the data, there was no trailing zero inside the called method unless you added one explicitly... I'm assuming that's why the OP added one.

Comment: Jeffora and James nailed it -- The DLL was looking for 1, not '1'!  Have I mentioned how much I love this site?  This is the biggest step forward for an online resource to improve developer productivity since DejaNews first came out.

Comment: SO has helped me out of my brain muck more times than I can count... no matter what time of the day/night I post a question : )  Thanks for the vote!

Comment: Just a small note, char[].ToString() as you've noted returns the string representation of the type name ('System.Char[]'). However, this doesn't mean that you need to use the encoding class to get that to a string, you just need to use the proper process i.e. string s = new string(someCharArray); The marshaller takes care of unicode vs ascii.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try to change the calling conventions?
In C++ you declare the function with pascal calling convention and in C# as stdcall.
The calling convention must match.